# Zabbix machine is going crazy with HD writes!

Tags: performance, hard-drive, zabbix

I recently installed Zabbix on a Ubuntu box I had sitting around. It's only monitoring 2 servers but I've noticed that it's continuously smashing the HD with writes. I don't remember Zabbix being this resource heavy when I've used it in the past...

Any ideas on why this is happening and what I can do about it?

Running iotop gives me this:

```
Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 431.19 K/s

1710 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s  102.12 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
1723 be/4 mysql       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld
```

I'm pretty sure it's Zabbix that's causing all that mysql activity as it's the only thing which uses mysql which is running on the box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was wrong and fix it.

I'd created a test item (to check if my original configuration was working properly) but the test item itself was failing and causing the continuous writes...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

how many new values per second ?
which version of zabbix ?
is mysql binlog disabled ?

Comment: It's Zabbix 1.8.2, mysql binlog is disabled. How do I check the number of new values per sec?